# c variable equals or memcpy

Tags: c

I have a 3d array `int main[N][N][N]` and I need to create a node structure that has `int buf[N][N]`.

When is it safe to use `buf = main[index]` vs `memcpy(buf,main[index],sizeof(main[index]));`?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to call a variable `main`. Does your compiler actually swallow it?

Answer (score 2):

If `buf` is an array, then it's not an lvalue. If it's not an lvalue, **you can never assign to it** (syntax error).

Answer (score 1):

If buf is a pointer and you don't need a copy, it's safe to use `=`. If buf is an array or pointer that is already allocated, what you usually do if you do need a copy, then `memcpy`

Answer (score 0):

If you're copying a contiguous portion of memory in C, `memcpy` is safe and possibly much more efficient than doing element by element copy. The reason that `memcpy` is potentially faster, is because various CPU tricks can be used to copy chunks larger than the machine word size. This is not always the case, however, and so profiling would be the only way for you to compare the two options.

Also, you probably meant to compare a for loop based copy and not a direct assignment, since assignment to an array variable is not valid C.

Comment: He isn't even doing element by element copy.

Comment: The "when is it safe to do so" phrase suggests that he really meant it the way he has written.